# Почему при использовании цикла while одно условие задачи выполняется, а второе - нет?

Tags: java, if, while

Я новичок, запуталась совсем. Поскольку не известно количество повторов, подумала решить эту задачу с помощью `while`. Одно условие задачи выполняется, а второе почему-то нет. Помогите, пожалуйста, советом.

Задача:

> Создаем программу, которая рассчитывает сумму вычета, получаемую работником. Суммы надбавок запрашиваются до тех пор, пока пользователь не установит "0". Размер вычета составляет 40% от оплаты труда.  
> Вычет рассчитывается так: `зарплата * 40 / 100,0 - 100`.

Примеры правильных ответов:

Пример 1.

```
Enter the amount of labor allowance (0 to stop): 500
Enter the amount of labor allowance (0 to stop): 250
Enter the amount of labor allowance (0 to stop): 400
Enter the amount of labor allowance (0 to stop): 50
Enter the amount of labor allowance (0 to stop): 0
The amount of household deduction is 380.00 euros.
```

Пример 2:

```
Enter the amount of labor allowance (0 to stop): 90
Enter the amount of labor allowance (0 to stop): 0
The amount of household deduction is 0.00 euros.
```

Мой хромой код:

```java
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class compensation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat des = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        double decrease, compensation, sum = 0.00;
                    
        System.out.print("Enter the amount of labor allowance (0 to stop): ");
        compensation = input.nextDouble();
        while (compensation > 0) {
            sum = sum + compensation;
            System.out.print("Enter the amount of labor allowance (0 to stop): ");
            compensation = input.nextDouble();
        }
        if (compensation > 0 && compensation >= 250) {
            decrease = 0;
            System.out.println("The amount of household deduction is " + des.format(decrease) + " euros");
        } else if (compensation < 250) {
            decrease = sum * 40 / 100.0 - 100;
            System.out.println("The amount of household deduction is " + des.format(decrease) + " euros");
        }
```

Comment: Какое одно условие? Какое второе условие? [ask]

Comment: Ответ невозможно дать, потому что  непонятно условие задачи, а также непонятна суть проблемы. Что в этом коде не так? Какая ошибка? Над чем работали? Что не получается? Просто выбросить неработающий код сюда, без указания причин, почему этот код не работает, или почему он работает неверно нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

В представленном коде условие выхода из цикла `while` -- `compensation <= 0`, то есть, если удалось выйти из цикла, данное условие выполнилось, но соответственно тогда первое условие в операторе `if (compensation > 0 && compensation >= 250)` **никогда** не будет выполнено.

К тому же это условие можно было бы упростить, так как два указанных диапазона сводятся к одному `if (compensation >= 250)`, соответственно в части `else` условие `else if (compensation < 250)` излишне, так как другим оно быть не может.

*Весьма вероятно*, что вместо последнего введённого значения `compensation` в условиях после цикла должна была проверяться сумма `sum`, тогда это имело бы какой-то смысл -- для дохода до 250 евро вычет равен 0, иначе используется формула.

Информации, представленной в ответе, должно быть достаточно для **самостоятельного исправления ошибок** в "хромом" коде.

Answer (score 1):

У вас избыточное количество переменных и дублирующий код. Обратите мнимание на эти 2 строки кода:

```
System.out.print("Enter the amount of labor allowance (0 to stop): ");
compensation = input.nextDouble();
```

Они повторяются и это явный признак того, что реализация кривая.

Кроме того, старайтесь избегать вложенности кода. если в цикл затолкать условный оператор, а потом в условный оператор затолкать еще один условнй оператор итд, то читаемость кода сильно ухудшается.

Посему попробуйте сделать так:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Compensation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat des = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        double inputValue, sum = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter the amount of labor allowance (0 to stop): ");
            inputValue = input.nextDouble();
            sum = sum + inputValue;
        }while (inputValue != 0);
        if (sum <= 250) System.out.println("The amount of household deduction is 0.00 euros"); 
        else System.out.println("The amount of household deduction is " + des.format(sum * 40 / 100.0 - 100) + " euros");
    }
}
```

Если есть вопросы - задавайте